# Is there a known relationship between the Intrinsic Dimensionality of a dataset and the VC dimension of a model?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, vc-dimension

We know that the Intrinsic Dimension of a dataset gives the low dimensional sub manifold in which the real data distribution lies. On the other hand, the VC dimension of a model gives the bounds for the number of data samples that the model can shatter. However, even after doing much research, I was unable to find whether there is any relation between the VC dimension of the model and the intrinsic dimensionality of the dataset. I know that there is a relation between the the dataset size and VC dimension but is there any relationship between the VC dimension and dimensionality of the dataset?

Comment: Something related can be found in the abstract and the introduction of: [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-012-5294-7#/page-1).